# Making a pong game, encountering odd glitches

Tags: javascript, html, pong

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Pong Game by Zach</title>
  <style>
    canvas {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      margin: auto;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function playGame(form) {
      var canvas;
      var ctx;
      var keystate;
      var canvasWidth = form.cWidth.value;
      var canvasHeight = form.cHeight.value;
      var ballSpeed = form.bSpeed.value;
      var playerSpeed = form.pSpeed.value;
      var playerWidth = form.pWidth.value;
      var playerHeight = form.pHeight.value;
      var movePlayer1Up = form.movePlayer1Up.value.charCodeAt(0) - 32;
      var movePlayer1Down = form.movePlayer1Down.value.charCodeAt(0) - 32;
      if (form.movePlayer2Up.value == "UpArrow") {
        var movePlayer2Up = 38;
      } else {
        var movePlayer2Up = form.movePlayer2Up.value.charCodeAt(0) - 32;
      }
      if (form.movePlayer2Down.value == "DownArrow") {
        var movePlayer2Down = 40;
      } else {
        var movePlayer2Down = form.movePlayer2Down.value.charCodeAt(0) - 32;
      }
      var player1 = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        score: null,
        width: playerWidth,
        height: playerHeight,
        update: function() {
          if (keystate[movePlayer1Up]) this.y -= playerSpeed;
          if (keystate[movePlayer1Down]) this.y -= -playerSpeed;
          this.y = Math.max(Math.min(this.y, canvasHeight - this.height), 0);
        },
        draw: function() {
          ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
      };
      var player2 = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        score: null,
        width: playerWidth,
        height: playerHeight,
        update: function() {
          if (keystate[movePlayer2Up]) this.y -= 7;
          if (keystate[movePlayer2Down]) this.y += 7;
          this.y = Math.max(Math.min(this.y, canvasHeight - this.height), 0);
        },
        draw: function() {
          ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
      };
      var ball = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        vel: null,
        side: 20,
        serve: function(side) {
          var r = Math.random();
          this.x = canvasWidth / 2;
          this.y = (canvasHeight - this.side) * r;
          var phi = 0.1 * Math.PI * (1 - 2 * r);
          this.vel = {
            x: side * ballSpeed * Math.cos(phi),
            y: ballSpeed * Math.sin(phi)
          }
        },
        update: function() {
          this.x += this.vel.x;
          this.y += this.vel.y;
          if (0 > this.y || this.y + this.side > canvasHeight) {
            var offset = this.vel.y < 0 ? 0 - this.y : canvasHeight - (this.y + this.side);
            this.y += 2 * offset;
            this.vel.y *= -1;
          }
          var AABBIntersect = function(ax, ay, aw, ah, bx, by, bw, bh) {
            return ax < bx + bw && ay < by + bh && bx < ax + aw && by < ay + ah;
          };
          var pdle = this.vel.x < 0 ? player1 : player2;
          if (AABBIntersect(pdle.x, pdle.y, pdle.width, pdle.height,
            this.x, this.y, this.side, this.side)) {
            this.x = pdle === player1 ? player1.x + player1.width : player2.x - this.side;
            var n = (this.y + this.side - pdle.y) / (pdle.height + this.side);
            var phi = 0.25 * Math.PI * (2 * n - 1);
            var smash = Math.abs(phi) > 0.2 * Math.PI ? 1.5 : 1;
            this.vel.x = smash * (pdle === player1 ? 1 : -1) * ballSpeed * Math.cos(phi);
            this.vel.y = smash * ballSpeed * Math.sin(phi);
          }
          if (0 > this.x + this.side || this.x > canvasWidth) {
            ballSpeed = 12;
            var isplayer1 = pdle === player1;
            player1.score += isplayer1 ? 0 : 1;
            player2.score += isplayer1 ? 1 : 0;
            this.serve(pdle === player1 ? 1 : -1);
          }
        },
        draw: function() {
          ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.side, this.side);
        }
      };

      function mplayer2n() {
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = canvasWidth;
        canvas.height = canvasHeight;
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        keystate = {};
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
          keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
        });
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
          delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
        });
        init();
        var loop = function() {
          update();
          draw();
          window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
        };
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
      }

      function init() {
        player1.x = player1.width;
        player1.y = (canvasHeight - player1.height) / 2;
        player2.x = canvasWidth - (player1.width + player2.width);
        player2.y = (canvasHeight - player2.height) / 2;
        player1.score = 0;
        player2.score = 0;
        ball.serve(1);
      }

      function update() {
        if (player1.score < 10 && player2.score < 10) {
          ball.update();
          player1.update();
          player2.update();
        }
      }

      function draw() {
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        player1.draw();
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        player2.draw();
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ball.draw();
        var w = 4;
        var x = (canvasWidth - w) * 0.5;
        var y = 0;
        var step = canvasHeight / 20;
        while (y < canvasHeight) {
          ctx.fillStyle = "white"
          ctx.fillRect(x, y + step * 0.25, w, step * 0.5);
          y += step;
        }
        ctx.font = "150px Georgia"
        var t = player1.score
        var v = player2.score
        ctx.fillText(t, canvas.width / 2 - ctx.measureText(t).width - 20, 100);
        ctx.fillText(v, canvas.width / 2 + 20, 100)
        if (player1.score > 9) {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
          ctx.fillStyle = "Black"
          ctx.font = "100px Georgia"
          var u = t + " - " + v
          var w = "Player 1 wins"
          ctx.fillText(w, canvas.width / 2 - ctx.measureText(w).width / 2, 130);
          ctx.font = "150px Georgia"
          ctx.fillText(u, canvas.width / 2 - ctx.measureText(u).width / 2, 300);
        } else if (player2.score > 9) {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
          ctx.fillStyle = "Black"
          ctx.font = "100px Georgia"
          var u = t + " - " + v
          var w = "Player 2 wins"
          ctx.fillText(w, canvas.width / 2 - ctx.measureText(w).width / 2, 130);
          ctx.font = "150px Georgia"
          ctx.fillText(u, canvas.width / 2 - ctx.measureText(u).width / 2, 300);
        }
        ctx.restore();
      }
      mplayer2n();
    }
  </script>

  <form action="">
    Settings:
    <br>Canvas Width:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="cWidth" value="1200">
    <br>Canvas Height:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="cHeight" value="600">
    <br>Ball Speed:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="bSpeed" value="12">
    <br>Player Speed:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="pSpeed" value="8">
    <br>Player Width:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="pWidth" value="20">
    <br>Player Height:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="pHeight" value="100">
    <br>Move Player 1 Up:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="movePlayer1Up" value="w">
    <br>Move Player 1 Down:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="movePlayer1Down" value="s">
    <br>Move Player 2 Up:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="movePlayer2Up" value="UpArrow">
    <br>Move Player 2 Down:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="movePlayer2Down" value="DownArrow">
    <br>Save Settings and start game:
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="Start" value="Start" onClick="playGame(this.form)">
    <br>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Above is the code that I have so far.

The part in question is the bottom part with the form and the part near the top where I am defining the variables for the settings.

I was making a pong game and it was working as expected until I tried to add a `<form>` so the player could customise the settings and controls.

I then set the variables I had used before to the values from this form. The problem was that when I when I added in the "player width" and "player height" variables. The game glitched out. Eg. The ball would bounce early, a paddle was missing etc.

Any ideas why this would occur when the data entered into the form was the same as the constants I had had before which worked perfectly fine.

Comment: without code, it would be hard to guess

Comment: "hard" == "impossible"

Comment: How can add my code, whenever I try to paste in my html, it just shows what would be shown on the website, not the code

Comment: indent with 4 spaces in front of each line

Comment: I added a code snippet, hopefully that clarifies things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the player width and player height in as **text**. You need to convert to integers. Do the same for player2.

```
var player1 = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    score: null,
    width: parseInt(playerWidth),
    height: parseInt(playerHeight),
```

Comment: Thank you very much, should I also do this for the other integer variables even they aren't causing problems at the moment?

Comment: For maintainability, you could. The reason the others work is because they are put into the DOM and will become text eventually anyways.